# Upload files to Angular or Rails

Tags: angularjs, file-upload, ruby-on-rails-4

I´m trying to integrate a Blueimp Jquery File Upload plugin in my application.

My application has an AngularJS front-end running in a Node.js server and a Rails API backend running in a WEBrick server.

I would like to clarify which is the best practices to store the files? In Angular (this case Node.js) server or the Rails one.

Thanks,
Roberto.

Comment: Are you asking where the best place to store the files after upload is?

Comment: @Davin, Maybe I don´t know how it works. I would like to know which server should I upload the files to (the Angular front-end Node.js or the Rails API back-end Webrick).

Comment: What is the relationship between the node.js app and the rails app.  Does node.js proxy calls to the rails back-end?

Comment: Angular applications run in web servers. Node.js is the web server for the angular front-end application. It will send GET and POST request to the Rails API in order to persist in DB or whatever...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm working on an app that has the exact same layout as yours and I came to the same question.

Since I'm trying to separate the back-end and front-end completely and have all the work with the db and files done in the back-end, I found that it's better to save the files in Rails server. That also gives you an option to do background operations with files (using [sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq), for example), without making users wait for completion in the front-end.

There are lots of tools for file upload from angularJS to the server (Rails), but I personally  found [angular-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload) directive easiest to understand and implement. I recommend you check it out.

I hope it helps,
Ulugbek

Comment: After some more research, I completely agree with you. Even I´m using the same directive. It works great. I´m really happy with it. I lost several days trying to integrate Jquery File Upload plugin which works fine but it´s extremely extremely complex to integrate or customize.

Comment: The directive seem to make the request directly when it the file has been selected. Any way you can select the file and by clicking another button make the request? I tried the first example that the README mentions but the $scope.myFile is not being set to an element https://github.com/leon/angular-upload#the-upload-service-can-be-used-this-way Any idea how to tackle this?

Comment: I couldn't find a solution to postpone the upload with this particular file uploader, so what I did was I uploaded it to a tmp folder, and only after the form was submitted, moved to the final folder in Rails.  Regarding setting the scope variable, I used the other example [here](https://github.com/leon/angular-upload#or-by-specifying-using-the-upload-button-with-a-normal-config) by specifying config for the upload button and it worked fine for me.